# Sharing data between Parent app and instant app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am designing an SDK. My SDK has it's own UI. To reduce the integration efforts I am planning to deploy the SDK as an instant app. The user will click the CTA to launch the SDK, which will launch the instant app.

My questions are:
1. Can I pass the sign up information of the user, to my instant app?
2. Also can I set colors of my app in accordance to the parent app?

If you find the question invalid, please specify the reason and then down vote or close the question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) yes you can pass the any type of values you want. You have to create some methods in your  instant app and just call them in your Parent app.
2) Also you can set method for theme in your instant app.

I have also designed an SDK for my parent app and i am passing the user info in my SDK.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, do you have any material where I can read more about this? Like a github repo or a blog that I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

1- You can pass information possibly as query parameters for the instant app URL. Depending on the sensitivity of these parameters, you may want to do a different approach, to make sure they're not intercepted by other apps in between. Maybe a more reliable approach is to for the integrating app to expose a ContentProvider to your instant app with these credentials.

2- For theming, you won't be sharing contexts with the integrating app, so you'll need to use the method you pick for (1) to also achieve this.

These aside, I think using instant apps for SDKs maybe a bit unreliable for multiple reasons:

- Instant apps need to have a corresponding full app available on Google Play, and users will need to be able to "upgrade" the instant app to a full app experience.
- Not all devices support instant apps yet. The coverage is increasing, but it's still not available to all devices.
- Even when a device supports instant app, the user can still opt out from a specific instant app, or disable all instant apps. You will need to have the URL invoking to your instant app work the same and provide same functionality through web browsers, if users don't go through the instant app.

Comment: Thanks for the points mentioned above, I will give them a thought. My approach was taking into perpective that users should not have to update their apps when I release a new version of my SDK, since I can directly update my Instant app. I think that will increase the adoption of my SDK.